# Decoding JSON with SWIFT CodingKeys Error

Tags: json, swift3, jsondecoder, swift-structs

I have the following data model which I am trying to decode JSON from an API into.

```
struct Data: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id =  UUID()
    let count: Count
    let risk: Risk
    let updatedAt: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case count = "Count"
        case risk = "Risk"
        case updatedAt
    }
}

struct Count: Codable {
    let grassPollen: Int
    let treePollen: Int
    let weedPollen: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case grassPollen = "grass_pollen"
        case treePollen = "tree_pollen"
        case weedPollen = "weed_pollen"
    }
}

struct Risk: Codable {
    let grassPollen: String
    let treePollen: String
    let weedPollen: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case grassPollen = "grass_pollen"
        case treePollen = "tree_pollen"
        case weedPollen = "weed_pollen"
    }
}

The JSON data I am tring to decode into the structure is as follows.
```

{
"message": "success",
"lat": 12,
"lng": 77,
"data": [
{
"Count": {
"grass_pollen": 51,
"tree_pollen": 34,
"weed_pollen": 26
},
"Risk": {
"grass_pollen": "Moderate",
"tree_pollen": "Low",
"weed_pollen": "Moderate"
},
"updatedAt": "2023-06-10T13:57:17.000Z"
}
]
}

```
I am getting the following error when the decode takes place. 
> 
> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "count", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"count\", intValue: nil) (\"count\").", underlyingError: nil))
>

I know the model has to have the same names etc. But I have been looking at this for ages and can't see what is wrong. I am just learning swift and am definitely a novice with JSON. 

So am I doing or missing something stupid? 





I have tried various versions of renaming the code and taking the COdingKeys out completely. If I change the coding key "Count" to something else it reflects that in the decode error, but despite trying various options. I'm stuck
```

Comment: I may have solved this and it is a cautionary tale if I have it correctly. 

I was using the decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

I think this is applied before the CodingKeys values. So I was looking for "Count" in the JSON which I think had already been converted to "count" and so the codingKeys were throwing up the error. 

I removed the decoder strategy and it all started to work. 